# Fetch data on Receive of Push Notification - ionic3

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, push-notification, ionic3

I am developing an ionic3 app targeting Android and ios and I am using Push notifications.I want to fetch some data from server on receiving push notification.I can't send my data as part of Push notification as Firebase restricts the max size of push message to be (4Kb).Hence, I am fetching data from server only when user taps on the Push notification which causes the user to wait until the data gets fetched from server.

Is there any way to fetch data on arrival of Push Notification (**App is not in Foreground**) ?

Comment: Yeah, you can start background service when you receive a push message and fetch data from the server there and when you fetched data from server successfully create the notification there.

Comment: Thanks @sasuke. Is there any way to create a Background service using ionic ?

Comment: Read concepts about promises

Comment: Please let me know how promises will help here?

Answer (score 0):

you use promises as a sort of 'callback handle' - do something asynchronous in a service, return a promise, and when the asynchronous work is done, the promise's then the function is triggered.

```
angular.module('atTheMoviesApp', [])
  .controller('GetMoviesCtrl', 
       function($log, $scope, movieService) {
           $scope.getMovieListing = function(movie) {
           var promise = 
               movieService.getMovie('avengers');
           promise.then(
              function(payload) { 
              $scope.listingData = payload.data;
        },
        function(errorPayload) {
            $log.error('failure loading movie', errorPayload);
        });
     };
})
.factory('movieService', function($http) {
return {
  getMovie: function(id) {
     return $http.get('/api/v1/movies/' + id);
  }
}
});
```

You can take a reference of the code from this [Link](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/)

Comment: This question is about neither Asynchronous task nor promises. How to create Background service which runs even when app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I am using "Phonegap-Plugin-Push" plugin for push notification with Firebase. This plugin calls on('notification') handler on arrival of push notification if push payload contains only 'data' object. Hence, Instead of adding 'notification' object to payload, I am sending only 'data' object as part of payload from server. Now, I am able to fetch data from server in my on('notification') handler as soon as the push notification arrives to device.

**Reference:** [PhonegapPluginPushDocs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md)